# Why Does Using ymd_hms Function Result in "All formats failed to parse. No formats found"?

Tags: r, lubridate

Trying to run mdy_hms. Getting the following:

```
> mdy_hms(gary)
[1] NA NA NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Input file is as follows:

```
encounter_id,disease_id,date
1,2,"04-17-2019 13:00:01"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: You need to pass in just the column you want to transform. You cannot pass the entire data.frame to `mdy_hms`

Answer (score 1):

It should work.
You need to use on the column and not the dataframe

```
lubridate::mdy_hms("04-17-2019 13:00:01")
"2019-04-17 13:00:01 UTC"
```

Comment: My file has 20 million rows.

Comment: Try `gary$date <- lubridate::mdy_hms(gary$date)`

Comment: Thanks, Sonny! As you can tell, I'm new to R. It makes sense now - easy for me to get mixed up between vectors, dataframes, etc.